# Can I replace Win-11 with Win-7 in a brand New System?

Tags: windows-7, replacement

I bought a new Dell workstation 3660 with

i-7 12700
2 NVIDIA T-600 Cards To Run 8 Monitors
Win-11 Pro
3 M.2 512GB NVMe & 3 SATA 4TB 5400 RPM HDDs
Eight 24 inch Monitors ( 1920 x 1200 ) Resolution

I am facing several issues like Font size + Clipped Fonts in Windows explorer file & folder names if I try to increase Text size or scale + 2 Monitors out of 8 has different resolution, Microphone does not work or detect etc. Very similar issues faced by many people using Windows-11.

Currently I am using 10 year old Dell workstation T-7500 with 12 Monitors & Win-7 with no issues for last 10 years. But now cpu & other fans are making noise & age gets to me so I bought above new Dell 3660 Workstation.

4 different Dell engineers have been working on it for last 2 weeks with no results.

I have never used any newer versions of Windows like Win-8 or 10. I have to finish the current project that I am working & I feel very comfortable with Win-7 even without any updates since 2020.

So my question is can I install Win-7 on a different New M.2 NVMe SSD & use it in current new system that I just bought with specs shown above ? And if yes or no, what problems would I run into it ?

Thank You.

Comment: can you? yes. should you? probably not. Windows 7 is EOL and not supported with updates, so it almost certainly has many security vulnerablilities.

Comment: If you have an OEM license you won't able to transfer your Windows 7 license to another machine.  If it's a retail license then you will run into the intentional design decision by Microsoft to block Windows 7 updates on newer processors.

Comment: >> But now cpu & other fans are making noise  Ramhound or someone will correct me if I'm mistaken, but it seems unlikely that the CPU is making noise. More likely its the power supply/fans or possibly the HDD. Replacing the power supply wouldn't be too expensive or difficult and might extend the life of your Win7 PC long enough to finish the project and buy you time to solve the various problems you're having with Win11

Answer (score 2):

Can I replace Win-11 with Win-7 in a brand New System?

Most unlikely. Microsoft has worked with manufacturers to preclude installing Windows 7 on new machines (so as to limit and stop Windows 7 which is now dead).

So you can do two things:

(1) Install Windows 7 as a virtual machine on your new system. This works - I have done it here.

(2) Use your older system with Windows 7 do do what you need in Windows 7.

Windows 11 works fine once you learn it and adapt to it.

Comment: Windows 7 might install but Windows Update won't work on any processor that is supported by Windows 11.  Microsoft at the request of AMD and Intel, pushed an update to Windows 7 before it went EOL, to prevent Windows Update from functioning on newer hardware..  I doubt any processor that formally supports Windows 11 would run Windows 7 at this point.

Comment: I doubt Win 7 would be able to find any drivers for brand new hardware, even without MS actively trying to stop you.